# Android NDK:Aborting

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have installed ndk correctly when working with previous projects.I have downloaded now openpeer library for Android. When I load the openpeer sdk, I get the following:

14:59:28 **** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project openpeer-android-sdk ****
"D:\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd" NDK_DEBUG=1 clean 
      2 [main] pwd 4928 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /cygdrive/d/Android Workspace/openpeer-android-sdk/jni/Android.mk
D:/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-application.mk:165: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

14:59:28 Build Finished (took 330ms)

I also got an error in the project but all of the files appear without any error signs. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the NDK_PROJECT_PATH environment variable..
Are you compiling over cygwin? what is the cygwin connection?

He tries to find some file at this path : /cygdrive/d/Android Workspace/openpeer-android-sdk/jni/Android.mk

Comment: the path is correct in environment variable but still the message is appearing.

Comment: You may be seeing an unworkable mix of cygwin-aware and ordinary-windows tools and values.  I don't expect a non-cygwin windows tool would do very well with a /cygdrive/d type path.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you please explain more?!